# laravel... insert a default profile when creating user

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `User` and `Profile` model with 1:1 relationship. When a user registers to my website I want to create a profile record with `defaultProfile` data associated with that user. Currently I'm using this approach and it works perfectly fine:

```
$newUser = $this->user->create($data);
$profile= new Profile($this->defaultProfile);
$newUser->profile()->save($profile);
```

However I want to know, is there any way to do so **without instantiating or even injecting** `Profile` model inside my code? Just by knowing the fact that User model `hasOne` Profile. I tried this code:

```
$newUser = $this->user->create($data);
$profile= $this->user->profile()->create($this->defaultProfile);
```

However, it tries to build a query which `user_id` is null. I also tried to hardcode "user_id" inside my `defaultProfile` array but it gives me the same error message:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `profiles` (`about`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (foo, , 2014-11-22 18:11:49, 2014-11-22 18:11:49))
```

Comment: `$user->profile()->create($profileData)` should work just fine. I think the problem might be that `$this->user->profile()->create()` should actually be `$newUser->profile()->create()`.

Comment: How stupid i am ;) thanks @Quasdunk. that was the problem. would you please send an answer